# C# tem suporte à GPS?

Tags: c#, .net, gps

É possível via um computador eu encontrar a localização de um celular com altitude, longitude e latitude utilizando C#?

Existe alguma biblioteca pra isso?

Preciso de algum hardware específico pra poder pôr em prática essa ideia de localização de um aparelho? (Que pode estar em qualquer lugar do mundo)

Tenho interesse em pegar algumas malas de viagem e colocar dentro delas um Arduino OU um celular para que eu possa via PC desktop rastrear a posição dessa mala em qualquer lugar do mundo. Digo desktop por conta do conforto de uma tela maior, não acho interessante ver a localização da mala pelo celular, podem ser várias. Também preciso das coordenadas exatas. É um TCC da faculdade.

Comment: Sem o celular reportar sua posição para algum serviço, acho que não é possível. O GPS é um sistema que o celular usa para saber sua própria posição, não dá pra saber a posição dos aparelhos sem que eles a informem a algum serviço.

Comment: Seria legal dar mais informações do que deseja, para que eu possa complementar minha resposta com algo que seja mais relevante ao que você quer. Respondi com o que eu tinha a disposição no momento.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O C# em si não tem esse suporte. Existem bibliotecas para trabalhar com GPS que funcionam com C#.

Mas o que parece que você quer é acessar a API de algum serviço que informa a localização de um celular.

Ou então você quer ter esse serviço construído em sua aplicação. Onde você precisará ter um software no dispositivo móvel para informar onde ele está e um outro software rodando em um servidor que vai receber estas informações.

Neste último caso, será só uma questão do software cliente pegar as informações disponíveis no *mobile* e enviar para um servidor (via TCP direto, UDP, etc. ou via tecnologias web como REST ou WebSockets). O servidor será uma aplicação apropriada para receber essas informações e fornecer a localização dos diversos dispositivos monitorados através uma tela ou API.

Hoje é raro o dispositivo móvel que não forneça esses dados, o hardware dele já tem tudo o que precisa e o sistema operacional fornece acesso a esta informação.

Do lado do servidor não precisa de nada especial além de uma conexão de rede estável e eventualmente um servidor de aplicação como o IIS ou Apache se optar por tecnologias web (tecnicamente é possível fazer sem mas quase todo mundo usará um servidor de aplicação padrão). Afinal ele só recebe informações.

Se você quer saber se um computador pode achar celulares por conta própria. Em princípio isso não é possível. Pelo menos, até onde eu sei, não em condições normais.

Algumas bibliotecas que podem ajudar dependendo do que vai fazer:

[NavTrack](https://github.com/navtrack/navtrack)

[GPS.Net](https://github.com/jperson2000/GPS.Net)

[OGL](https://ogl-lib.sourceforge.net/)

[SharpGPS](https://github.com/fivepmtechnology/SharpGPS)

Não as conheço e não sei se resolvem o seu problema. Só estou colocando para te dar um início de estudo.

Além disso o Xamarin tem suporte ao GPS dos dispositivos móveis.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).